# I just upgraded to Marshmallow and now my views are not working

Tags: android, imageview, android-6.0-marshmallow, viewgroup

I assume my recent upgrade to Android 6.0 has something to do with my inability to have my images appear when I run my apps. I recently upgraded my Samsung S6 from Lollipop to Marshmallow and all of my apps that worked just fine with Lollipop now refuse to show any of my views outside of my xml code. Has anyone else encountered this? If anyone has an answer I would greatly appreciate it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Display mainDisplay;
ViewGroup mainLayout;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutPositioner;
ImageView pracimg;
float offsetX = 0.0f;
float offsetY = 0.0f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//Remove title bar
    //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//Hides notification bar
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)

    mainDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.id_layout);

    DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(m);
    int windowHeight = m.heightPixels;
    int windowWidth = m.widthPixels;

    offsetX = (windowWidth / 1440.0f);
    offsetY = (windowHeight / 2560.0f);

    pracimg = new ImageView(this);
    SetPos(0, 0, 1440, 2560);
    pracimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.submarinesandwich);
    pracimg.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(pracimg);
}

public void SetPos(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    layoutPositioner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutPositioner.topMargin = (int) (offsetY * y);
    layoutPositioner.leftMargin = (int) (offsetX * x);
    layoutPositioner.width = (int) (width * offsetX);
    layoutPositioner.height = (int) (height * offsetY);
}

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_layout"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop = "0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "1440dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "2560dp"
    android:orientation = "horizontal" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As just an observation remove `android:orientation = "horizontal"` from your `RelativeLayout` - no such param exists for `RelativeLayout`.  Also you have hardcoded dp margin values, why do you need them when its your root layout, especially with values of `2560dp` the layout contents won't have any room?

Comment: Thanks after I removed the margin and horizontal lines its working normal